# Pandoc --resource-path not finding assets

Tags: pandoc

I am using the pandoc/latex docker container and having some issues with `--resource-path`. My project is using a latex template which references an image, and I cannot get latex to find the image.

My file tree looks like this:

```
/app/tmp/
├── 42
│   ├── galley.md
│   └── img
│       ├── 1.jpg
│       ├── 5.jpg
│       ├── 7.jpg
│       └── 9.jpg
```

And I have user data dirs like this:

```
/home/worker/.pandoc
├── assets
│   └── logo.png
└── templates
    └── sow.latex
```

The command I'm using looks like

```
pandoc --from markdown --to latex /app/tmp/42/galley.md --output=/app/tmp/42/2/out.pdf --template sow.latex --resource-path=.:/home/worker/.pandoc/assets
```

As mentioned the latex template does make a reference to `logo.png`:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{logo.png}\par\vspace{1cm}
```

Whenever I run pandoc I get the following error:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `logo.png' not found: using draft setting.
```

If I comment out the reference to `logo.png` then everything works fine including the other images referenced within `galley.md`. Likewise if I copy `logo.png` into the directory with `galley.md` everything works fine; as a workaround that is fine, but it feels quite clangy so I would rather sort out how to reference `logo.png` from where it sits in `assets`.

Is there something I've missed about how `reference-path` plays with `template`?

Comment: Absolute paths work as well, so I'll just use those until a more general solution presents itself.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with templates - I am using the anaconda version of pandoc 2.11 and can only get it to work with absolute paths. Following the documentation,  I created a folder `~/.pandoc`, to no avail. Specifying the directory via `--data-dir=/~/.pandoc` does also not help